# Experience custom theme and components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, experience-builder-page, experience-cloud, digital-experience

I have created site through digital experience and build you own template. But I don’t get how to add custom themes and components? I tried trailhead https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/communities_theme_layout but it doesn’t work with build your own. I didn’t found anything in settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Trailhead Module that you pointed is for Aura Components and does not apply much for the LWR Build your own template.

Here are some resources to help you with LWR Templates

- [LWR Sites for Experience Cloud Developer Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/intro.htm)
- [Code Samples](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/intro_resources.htm#code_sample)

**Create Custom Layout**

To answer your specific question on how to create a [custom layout in LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/get_started_layout.htm), use below code

```
<template>
  <header class='slds-col_padded slds-p-vertical_small'>
    <slot name="header"></slot>
  </header>
 <section class='slds-col_padded slds-p-vertical_small'>
    <slot name="sidebar"></slot>
  </section>
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

 /**
  * @slot header
  * @slot sidebar
  */
export default class CustomThemeLayout extends LightningElement {}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="customPageLayout">
  <apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
   <isExposed>true</isExposed>
   <masterLabel>Your Custom Page Layout</masterLabel>
   <description>A custom layout</description>
   <targets>
    <target>lightningCommunity__Page_Layout</target>  
  </targets>
 </LightningComponentBundle>
```

**Create a Theme Layout**

For a theme layout, a sample LWC Component would be as below

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <header data-f6-region style={headerStyle}>
        <slot name="header"></slot>
    </header>
    <section data-f6-region style={sectionStyle}>
        <slot></slot>
    </section>
    <footer data-f6-region style={footerStyle}>
        <slot name="footer"></slot>
    </footer>
   </div>
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

 /**
 * @slot header
 * @slot footer
 * @slot default
 */
  export default class blankThemeLayout extends LightningElement {
    @api backgroundColor = '#fff';

    renderedCallback() {
    this.template.querySelector(".container").style.backgroundColor = this.backgroundColor;
  }
 }
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="blankThemeLayout">
  <apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
  <isExposed>true</isExposed>
  <masterLabel>Blank Theme Layout (LWC)</masterLabel>
   <targets>
    <target>lightningCommunity__Theme_Layout</target>
    <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
</targets>

    <targetConfigs>
     <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
        <property name="backgroundColor" type="Color" default="#fff"></property>
      </targetConfig>
   </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

The key thing to understand is similar to attributes in the aura component, slots with the same names are provided for LWR Communities.

Comment: Thanks, got it.